# Can an Android application be coded for Mobile Devices and Computers?

Tags: android, cross-platform

If I create a Android Application that uses on screen buttons, can I also code it to listen for keyboard keystrokes if it is running on a PC? So what I'm saying is, if I develop a application that can run on mobile devices and PC, can I keep the code for both of them the same, and still listen to keyboard strokes in both versions?

So if I open the app on a mobile device it will use touch screen, and if I open the same app on my computer it will use the keyboard for input, is this possible?

Comment: Android apps do not run "on a PC" that runs Windows, which I presume is your PC operating system of interest given your choice of tags.

Comment: BlueStack does allow for this, but it emulates an Android Device.

Comment: AFAIK, it is not strictly an emulator, but rather a virtualized environment, much like VirtualBox or VMWare. It would be up to BlueStacks to handle any sort of keyboard mapping, and questions regarding that mapping would need to be asked of BlueStacks. IOW, your real question is "how does my Android app behave on BlueStacks", and that is best answered by BlueStacks.

Answer (score 0):

My friend Android platform is only available for mobile devices and their hardware is designed in such a way so that only android platform can be installed on it. For PC we have other platforms like Windows, LINUX etc. So for running android application on PC you need to have a android platform which can be installed on PC. Till now there is no android platform which can be installed on PC. But may be available in future. Then you can think on your Question.

**Have Fun and Wait to have another new innovation in android so that this will be available for PC also**